# Text uppercase option in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, uppercase, lowercase

Just imagine I have defined a list of static variables in lower case on my editor.

Is there any option in intellij where I can select a portion of my source code and convert it into either upper/lower case?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two options available.

1. Use toggle case action

   - Select text
   - Invoke Edit | Toggle Case action or

     Keyboard shortcut:
     Windows & Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
     Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
2. Use [find and replace text using regular expressions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#upper_lower_case_switch)

   - Select text
   - Invoke Edit | Find | Replace… action or

     Keyboard shortcut:
     Windows & Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
     Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
   - Choose the "Search In Selection" & "Regex" search options
   - Search for `(.+)` to select all characters and include them in a single capturing group
   - Use `\U$1` as the replacement, which replaces all characters in the capturing group with the uppercase equivalent
   - Click "Replace All" to perform the text replacement